# Read object from bucket using cognos

Tags: amazon-web-services, cognos-11, cloud-object-storage

Does aws object storage allow for the reading of objects from buckets using IBM cognos?

Wanted to read the object from aws cloud object storage using IBM cognos.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=storage-creating-connection-cloud-object-provider

Does aws object storage allow for the reading of objects from buckets using IBM cognos?

Wanted to read the object from aws cloud object storage using IBM cognos.